# Remove You've Already Submitted Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My clients wants to be able to submit a form multiple times and this AMPscript only lets you submit it once. What do I need to remove from the AMPscript to allow it to process multiple submissions by the same subscriber?

I thought removing this line only would work, but it doesn't display any of the alerts when removed: `elseif @deNumRows >0` then `set @duplicatedFound = 'You have already submitted your information.'`

---

```
if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then

var @email, @fullName, @accountNumber, @zipCode, @companyName,
@checkZip, @numRows, @checkDE, @deNumRows, @createDeRecord,
@success, @fail

set @fullName = RequestParameter('fullName')

set @accountNumber = RequestParameter('accountNumber')

set @email = RequestParameter('email')

set @zipCode = RequestParameter('zipCode')

set @companyName = RequestParameter('companyName')

set @companyURL = RequestParameter('companyURL')

set @checkZip = LookupRows('ZipCodes', 'ZipCode', @zipCode)

set @numRows = RowCount(LookupRows('ZipCodes','ZipCode',@zipCode))

set @checkDE = LookupRows('Capture', 'EmailAddress', @email)

set @deNumRows =
RowCount(LookupRows('Capture','EmailAddress',@email))
if @numRows >0 AND @deNumRows == 0 then

set @createDeRecord = InsertDE(
'Capture',
'FullName', @fullName,
'AccountNumber', @accountNumber,
'EmailAddress', @email,
'ZipCode', @zipCode,
'CompanyName', @companyName)

set @success = 'Success'

elseif @numRows == 0 then

     set @createDeRecord = InsertDE(
    'Capture',
    'FullName', @fullName,
    'AccountNumber', @accountNumber,
    'EmailAddress', @email,
    'ZipCode', @zipCode,
    'CompanyName', @companyName)

set @fail = 'Fail.'

elseif @deNumRows >0 then
set @duplicatedFound = 'You have already submitted your information.'

endif
endif
endif
endif
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UpsertData()` function, if you want the form to be submitted multiple times. This function will insert the data when data extension is empty and update it when the data is already present.

**Syntax:**

UpsertData(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

1   ->  Name of data extension from which to update the specified row

2   -> numeric  Required    Number of columns used to build WHERE clause

3   -> string   Required    Column name to build WHERE clause

4   -> string   Required    Value used to build WHERE clause

5   -> string   Required    Column name to build INSERT clause

6   ->string    Required    Value used to build INSERT clause

Your code will look something like this.

```
if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then

var @email, @fullName, @accountNumber, @zipCode, @companyName,
@checkZip, @numRows, @checkDE, @deNumRows, @createDeRecord,
@success, @fail

set @fullName = RequestParameter('fullName')

set @accountNumber = RequestParameter('accountNumber')

set @email = RequestParameter('email')

set @zipCode = RequestParameter('zipCode')

set @companyName = RequestParameter('companyName')

set @companyURL = RequestParameter('companyURL')

set @checkZip = LookupRows('ZipCodes', 'ZipCode', @zipCode)

set @numRows = RowCount(LookupRows('ZipCodes','ZipCode',@zipCode))

set @checkDE = LookupRows('Capture', 'EmailAddress', @email)

set @deNumRows =
RowCount(LookupRows('Capture','EmailAddress',@email))
if @numRows >0 AND @deNumRows == 0 then

set @createDeRecord = UpsertData(
'Capture',1,'EmailAddress', @email,'ZipCode', @zipCode,
'FullName', @fullName,
'AccountNumber', @accountNumber,
'CompanyName', @companyName)

set @success = 'Success.'

elseif @numRows == 0 then

     set @createDeRecord = UpsertData(
    'Capture',1,    'EmailAddress', @email,'ZipCode', @zipCode,
    'FullName', @fullName,
    'AccountNumber', @accountNumber,
    'CompanyName', @companyName)

set @fail = 'Fail.'

elseif @deNumRows >0 then
set @duplicatedFound = 'You have already submitted your information.'

endif
endif
endif
endif
]%%
```

Comment: What if they want each submission to be Added and not Updated?

Comment: You should setup a primary key in the data extension and each time when you call a INSERTDATA function, you will have to keep a unique value which will act as PK and your form will be submitted.

Comment: Email is being used as the unique value.